# Kubuntu 19.10 application-switcher application order always wrong

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, plasma-5

There are multiple things wrong in my application-switcher.

(problem A):
When i use Alt-tab i see the application-switcher but the order is reversed. So the appication that had focus before i pressed alt-tab, is shown at the end as the last item in the application-switcher.

(problem B):
Also when i press alt-tab the first application that will be selected is the application in the beginning of the list (so that should actualy the last application).
Pressing alt-tab again will go to the application that had focus before i started.

(problem C):
When i try to switch the shortcuts from alt-tab to alt-shift-tab and the other way around. It will still work the same. So that change seem to be saving and all. But i can't see any behaviour change when pressing alt-tab.
But the shortcut does work somehow, because when i remove the shortcuts alt-tab does not work anymore.

Any ideas? Is there something i can reset to get this working as it should?

Kind regards,
Barry.